# How do I remove a Heroku build error because of Console Browserify

Tags: heroku

I cannot seem to build from github because of the below error.
Does anyone have an idea of the error and how to fix it?

```
       Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /tmp/build_69fe27ea/node_modules/console-browserify/index.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
       You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.
```

console-browserify is being imported by the node-polyfill-webpack-plugin

```
node-polyfill-webpack-plugin@^1.1.4:
  version "1.1.4"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin/-/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin-1.1.4.tgz#56bfa4d16e17addb9d6b1ef3d04e790c401f5f1d"
  integrity sha512-Z0XTKj1wRWO8o/Vjobsw5iOJCN+Sua3EZEUc2Ziy9CyVvmHKu6o+t4gUH9GOE0czyPR94LI6ZCV/PpcM8b5yow==
  dependencies:
    assert "^2.0.0"
    browserify-zlib "^0.2.0"
    buffer "^6.0.3"
    console-browserify "^1.2.0"
    constants-browserify "^1.0.0"
    crypto-browserify "^3.12.0"
    domain-browser "^4.19.0"
    events "^3.3.0"
    filter-obj "^2.0.2"
    https-browserify "^1.0.0"
    os-browserify "^0.3.0"
    path-browserify "^1.0.1"
    process "^0.11.10"
    punycode "^2.1.1"
    querystring-es3 "^0.2.1"
    readable-stream "^3.6.0"
    stream-browserify "^3.0.0"
    stream-http "^3.2.0"
    string_decoder "^1.3.0"
    timers-browserify "^2.0.12"
    tty-browserify "^0.0.1"
    url "^0.11.0"
    util "^0.12.4"
    vm-browserify "^1.1.2"
```

Comment: How are you trying to import that module? Please [edit] the relevant code into your question.

Comment: It's being imported by a package, so I have little control over the import. It works runs/builds on my local machine but not on Heroku